# Does quasi-projective imply quasi-compact (in the Zariski topology)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbf{C})$ be a quasi-projective variety.

Q: Is $X$ necessarily quasi-compact in the Zariski topology (if yes then how to prove it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say, any subset of a Noetherian topological space is quasi-compact with respect to the induced topology.

Comment: yes you're right, that was a dumb question

Comment: @HugoChapdelaine no problem, happens to all of us

Comment: nevertheless, your solution gives the right point of view.

Comment: In fact Noetherian is equivalent to "hereditarily compact."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sure, that's actually a criterion. Thank you for the term though, have never heard of this one.